# What is the importance of normal line to a curve?

Tags: calculus, curves

I know that tangent line to a curve is too important as it has ample application in different areas such as velocity, rate of change. But I don't really know the importance of **normal lines** except they taught us by defining them using tangent lines.

Comment: [Real life example:](https://www.intmath.com/applications-differentiation/1-tangent-normal.php) "When you are going fast around a circular track in a car, the force that you feel pushing you outwards is normal to the curve of the road." Also, the spokes of a bicycle wheel are normal to the rim.

Comment: one comment might be that it is a fairly good information about a point on a curve. Suppose you take a point on the curve. This says nothing but curve passes from that point, which tells nothing about 'behaviour' of the curve. On the other hand, if you know the tangent, this is more than a single point but how it behaves nearby that point. For example, if your curve is a line, basically you get all the information.

Comment: What do you know about centripetal force?